# Angular `CORS` policy Eroro

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, mean-stack

I’m using the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular, and NodeJS).
There is a simple function to get data from an external API like this:

```js
let api = 'https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/city';
return this.http.get<any>(api).subscribe(res => { this.data = res; });
```

But whenever it sends a request, I get the following error:

```
"OPTIONS https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/city 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/city' from origin 'http://localhost:4040' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."
```

My Chrome has web security disabled, with the CORS extension installed, and my app is configured to enable CORS on the server side.

When I use Postman to do this, it is working well.

Comment: Can you show us the BE code aswell?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i don't know what is 'BE code'

Comment: Since CORS is a server error, I believe who made the API forgot to add `("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: Since you're calling external api, the resource at external api `https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/city'` should allow CORS, there's is no work around

Answer (score -1):

In node js you have fix this issue in 2 type

**Type 1**

install **cors**

`npm install cors`

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

// cors config
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    next();
});

app.listen(8083, () => {
    console.log('Server connected with 8083');
})
```

**Type 2**

`npm install browser-sync --save`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.crt', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log('Server connected with 8080');
});

httpsServer.listen(8081,()=>{
    console.log('Server connected with 8081');
});
```

In that way you provide express middleware to the native http/https server

If you want your app running on ports below 1024, you will need to use sudo command (not recommended) or use a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx, haproxy).

Comment: Have you got answer

Answer (score -2):

You can use this in your Node.js application entry point

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Or

You can use response object to set the header

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Hopefully this should solve the problem.